# Laravel 5 migrations : default length of different types in Schema::table method

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm setting up a migration on Laravel 5 and was wondering if there was some documentation for the default lengths of each of the Column Types ? Do they follow some convention like MySQL's?

Ex:
    INTEGER,
    TEXT,
    MEDIUMTEXT,
    LONGTEXT

I'm talking about these Column Types :
(http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#adding-columns)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Laravel's 5.0 documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20150822124019/http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_char), I guess the default of 255 is imposed on `string()` and `char()` methods.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 42):

#### String types

**CHAR** - `1 to 191` (trailing spaces removed)

**STRING** - `1 to 16,300` (user defined)

**TEXT** - `1 to 65,535`

**MEDIUMTEXT** - `1 to 16,777,215`

**LONGTEXT** - `1 to 4,294,967,295`

---

#### Integer types

**TINYINT** - `0 to 255` (unsigned) | `-128 to 127` (signed)

**SMALLINT** - `0 to 65,535` (unsigned) | `-32,768 to 32,767` (signed)

**MEDIUMINT** - `0 to 16,777,215` (unsigned) | `-8,388,608 to 8,388,607` (signed)

**INT** - `0 to 4,294,967,295` (unsigned) | `-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647` (signed)

**BIGINT** - `0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615` (unsigned) | `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807` (signed)

---

#### Floating types

Structure: `([max decimal places], [max precision])`

**FLOAT** - `([0-7], [0-23])`

**DOUBLE** - `([0-14], [24-53])`

**DECIMAL** - `([0-65], [0-30])`

---

See all column type for laravel:  [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#creating-columns)

Answer (score 10):

`INTEGER` range `0-4294967295` (unsigned) or from `-2147483648 to 2147483647` (signed) [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)

`TEXT` max size `65,535` characters [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-type-overview.html)

`MEDIUMTEXT` max size `16,777,215` characters [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-type-overview.html)

`LONGTEXT` max size `4,294,967,295` characters [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-type-overview.html)

More you can find on mysql site which looks like was used by laravel authors.